# Passing Data to Respective Textboxes from DataGrid after clicking particular Row in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am to new WPF. I need to pass the data from DataGrid to textboxes. I searched many sites but all were explaining by considering DataGridview (which has event called CellContentClick) but that event is not there in DataGrid (I am using vs2010).

I have defined textboxes in Usercontrol and used that in mainwindow for 4 Tabs.

1.MainWindow.xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl1">
        <TabItem Header="View Details" x:Name="Tab1">
            <StackPanel>
                <uc:CustomerUC x:Name="ViewData"></uc:CustomerUC>
                <Button Content="UpdateDataGrid" Height="25" Width="180" Name="UpGridBtn" Click="UpGridBtn_Click" Margin="15" Visibility="{Binding UpGridVisibility}"/>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersData}" x:Name="DGdata"  Margin="0 20 0 10">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerID" Binding="{Binding Path=CustoID}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerName" Binding="{Binding Path=CustoName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerAge" Binding="{Binding Path=CustoAge}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerAddress" Binding="{Binding Path=CustoAddress}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerEmail" Binding="{Binding Path=CustoEmail}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerMobile" Binding="{Binding Path=CustoMobile}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerUserName" Binding="{Binding Path=CustoUname}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>

            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Add Details" x:Name="Tab2">
            <uc:CustomerUC x:Name="AddData"></uc:CustomerUC>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Update Details" x:Name="Tab3">
            <uc:CustomerUC x:Name="UpdateData"></uc:CustomerUC>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Delete Details" x:Name="Tab4">
            <uc:CustomerUC x:Name="DeleteData"></uc:CustomerUC>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

2.Usercontrol code

```
<StackPanel >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding CustIDVisibility}" >
        <Button x:Name="CustID" Content="Customer ID" Width="100" Margin="82 0 0 0" Click="CustID_Click"  />
        <ComboBox Height="25" Width="180" x:Name="ComboID" SelectionChanged="ComboID_SelectionChanged" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding CustomerIDVisibility}" >
        <Label x:Name="CustoID" Content="Customer ID" Width="100"  Margin="82 0 0 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxID" Margin="2" Width="180" Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoID}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label x:Name="CustName" Content="Customer Name" Width="100"  Margin="82 0 0 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxName" Margin="2" Width="180" Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label  x:Name="CustAge" Content=" Age" Width="100" Margin="82 0 0 0"/>
        <TextBox  x:Name="BoxAge" Margin="2" Width="180" Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoAge}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label x:Name="CustAddress" Content="Address" Width="100" Margin="82 0 0 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxAddress" Margin="2" Width="180" Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoAddress}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label x:Name="CustEmail" Content="Email ID" Width="100" Margin="82 0 0 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxEmail" Margin="2" Width="180" Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoEmail}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label x:Name="CustMobile" Content="Mobile No." Width="100" Margin="82 0 0 0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxMobile" Margin="2" Width="180" Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoMobile}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label x:Name="CustUname" Content="User Name"  Width="100" Margin="82 0 0 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxUname" Margin="2" Width="180" Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoUname}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding pwdVisibility}" >
        <Label x:Name="CustPWD" Content="Password" Width="100" Margin="82 0 0 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxPWD" Margin="2" Width="180" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="82 15 0 0" >
        <Button x:Name="CancelBtn" Content="Cancel" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="SaveBtn"  Content="Save" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding SaveVisibility}" Click="SaveBtn_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="UpdateBtn" Content="Update" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding UpdateVisibility}" Click="UpdateBtn_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="DeleteBtn" Content="Delete" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding DeleteVisibility}" Click="DeleteBtn_Click" />
    </StackPanel>


</StackPanel>
```

//

3.Model Code

```
 class CustomerDataModel
{
    public int CustoID { get; set; }
    public string CustoName { get; set; }
    public int CustoAge { get; set; }
    public string CustoAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustoEmail { get; set; }
    public string CustoMobile { get; set; }
    public string CustoUname { get; set; }
}
```

//

4. View Model Code

   public CustoDataPassVM()
       {
           FillGrid();
       }
       public void FillGrid()
       {
           PurchaseNowEntities Entity = new PurchaseNowEntities();
           var datalist = from r in Entity.tblCustomerDetails select r;

   ```
       if (CustomersData == null)
           CustomersData = new ObservableCollection<CustomerDataModel>();

       foreach (var r in datalist)
       {
           CustomersData.Add(new CustomerDataModel
           {
               CustoID = r.CustomerID,
               CustoName = r.CustomerName,
               CustoAge = r.CustomerAge,
               CustoAddress = r.CustomerAddress,
               CustoEmail = r.CustomerEmailID,
               CustoMobile = r.CustomerMobile,
               CustoUname = r.CustomerUname
           });
       }
   }
   ```

5.With help of datacontext i am able to get data in datagrid

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CO = new CustoDataPassVM();
        DGdata.DataContext = CO;
    }
```

[Output screenshots pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhIzE.png)

If i use both textbox and datagrid in SAME WINDOW  i will be able to get data on textboxes with help of

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=DGdata, Path=SelectedItem.CustoID}
```

But when i separate the datagrid in mainwindow and textboxes in Usercontrol. I think it is not  finding datagrid of  ElementName= DGdata in usercontrol window, so it is  not binding in texboxes i think.

So how to pass data of datagrid(selected row) from mainwindow to usercontrol textboxes

And I tried with SelectionChanged handler, in this i am to get each cell value, but it is not bind to textboxes( ex: BoxName.text is getting assigned but not in textbox of it..

SelectionChanged handler code:

```
public void DGdata_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerUC bindnow = new CustomerUC();
        CustomerDataModel row = (CustomerDataModel)DGdata.SelectedItem;
        bindnow.BoxName.Text = row.CustoName;

    }
```

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you

Comment: You could Bind the datacontext of that part of your view details which has the customer data in it to the selecteditem of the datagrid. If you synchronise the datagrid select item with current https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=netframework-4.7.2 then you could use / notation binding to the current item of the default view of the data you bind to the datagrid. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29859.wpf-tips-bind-to-current-item-of-collection.aspx

Comment: @DanieleSartori I have added some code information, will this help you to get solutions for me

Comment: You can work with the Datagrid's SelectionChanged Handler. Your Main Window should be aware of the user control, you can inject the selected Object from the DataGrid to your user control in it

Comment: @DanieleSartori i am able to get data of each cell in this event but not able to assign to textboxes, i have added code of it check it once

Comment: @Sunil are you Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the viewmodel of you user control? If yes, you should be able to access the property which you are bounding your text and set it